# How to set proxy authorization in libcurl

Tags: libcurl

Actually I am trying to post some data to the URL.But I am getting stuck because of proxy.
The below code snippet is always giving proxy authorization required even though setting the values.
Please let me know any thing needs to be changed in the code.
Here is the code snippet that I am using

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxy proxy.xyz.com:8080");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, "CURLPROXY_HTTP");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "abc/xyz:pwd");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jsonResult);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://username:password@url");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, error);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

if(res != CURLE_OK)
{
fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
curl_easy_strerror(res));
return false;
}
```

I have used the CURLOPT_VERBOSE option
Below is the output

```
* About to connect() to proxy proxy.xyz.com port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying proxy ip... * connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'abc/xyz'
> POST http://username:password@url HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic aW5kaWEvNjY2NTU3Ok5vdkAyMDE0
Host:ip:8080
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 53
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 53 out of 53 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required
< Date: Thu, 04 Dec 2014 05:17:15 GMT
< Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain
< Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Language: en
< Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate
< Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
< Content-Length: 322
<
<HEAD><TITLE>Proxy Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Proxy Authorization Required</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Proxy Authorization Required" response (407) -->
</BODY>
* Connection #0 to host proxy.xyz.com left intact
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Please refer the above code snippet @2501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still get a 407 back, it means the proxy rejected the credentials (or method) you used.

Set CURLOPT_VERBOSE and verify that the request looks like you want it and double-check that the proxy really accepts what you send it.

CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE is not a string so the code you shown above will not work. In fact, proxy type HTTP is default if not set so you can just remove that line.

Finally, not related to your problem, but using CUSTOMREQUEST like that is not recommended since POSTFIELDS already implies a POST.

Comment: I have used CURLOPT_VERBOSE option.Above mentioned the output of VERBOSE option.I am unable to identify what is the problem to connect to proxy.Can you please let me know the cause.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel.After seeing your comment,I checked for the credentials and method used for giving credentials.Finally my issue is resolved.Actually the problem is I have used CURLOPT_USERPWD option to set the proxy username and password.But the option for setting proxy username and password is CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD.Now it is giving  "502 No route to host error".Please guide me how to look into this issue.